# Customizing Alfresco version labeling policy?

Tags: versioning, alfresco

[Alfresco Wiki Versioning](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Versioning) section "Version meta-data, version numbers and version labels":

> The generation of the version label
>   can be customized by creating a
>   version label policy behaviour and
>   registering it in place of the default
>   version label policy.

Where is this documented?